# Quelle est la difference entre 'en même temps' et 'au même temps' ?

Tags: expressions, usage, prépositions

J'ai vérifié, et les deux expressions sont utilisées. Voir:

[en même temps](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=en%20m%C3%AAme%20temps)

[au même temps](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=au%20m%C3%AAme%20temps)

Comment: *Au même temps* ne se dit plus depuis très longtemps.  On dit : **en même temps** — **au même moment** — **au même instant**.

Comment: _Au même temps_ sonne comme une erreur pour des oreilles hexagonales modernes.

Answer (score 3):

On trouve encore la locution *au même temps* dans la [7<sup>e</sup> édition](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A7T0329) (1878)  du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* comme synonyme de *en même temps*. Par contre elle a disparu de la [8<sup>e</sup> édition](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8T0340) (1935). Les dictionnaires contemporains ne donnent plus la locution ([Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/temps) et [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/temps/77238), par exemple, ne donnent que *en même temps*). Je n'ai jamais  entendu *au même temps* en France, et ne l'ai lu que dans des textes vraiment anciens. Tous les dictionnaires bilingues que je viens de consulter ne donnent que *en même temps* pour "zur gleichen zeit", "at the same time", "al mismo tiempo".

[Un article de *20 Minutes*](https://www.20minutes.fr/societe/langue_francaise/4072502-20240203-temps-temps-faut-ecrire) nous dit que :

> rare chez les francophones natifs, la confusion entre « en même temps » et « au même temps » se rencontre souvent chez les étrangers qui apprennent le français.

Cette confusion figure même dans les erreurs à ne pas commettre dans [20 erreurs courantes en français](https://parlez-vous-french.com/20-erreurs-courantes-en-francais/) :

> Erreur #10 : “J’écoute et je lis l’histoire au même temps.”
> Pour parler de deux actions qui se passent simultanément, dans un même instant, on utilise les locutions “en même temps” ou “au même moment”.

Je ne sais pas si *au même temps* se dit en tant que synonyme de *en même temps*<sup>*</sup> dans d'autres pays francophones, si c'était le cas ça pourrait expliquer ces quelques occurrences dans *Lingue*. Mais mon conseil à un non francophone est de ne pas l'utiliser, car ça peut être considéré comme une erreur.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> Bien entendu il est tout à fait possible de rencontrer les mots *au même temps* où temps désigne un temps de conjugaison (« ces deux verbes sont au même temps »).</sup>

Comment: Les dates des différentes éditions du Dictionnaire de l'Académie ont été permutées.

Comment: @Bruno         Merci pour ton œil attentif  !